# When ArrayList is updated in Model JList should be updated in View

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, arraylist, jlist

I've been playing around with this for a while now with no success.  I've had a look at ListModel but have struggled to implement it into my current project.

I have a Producer class thread adding elements to an ArrayList in the Model.  This works fine and the ArrayList is being updated at runtime.  My problem is, I then want the new objects added to the ArrayList to be added to the JList in the View class.  I can't see how to incorperate ListModel or DefaultListModel into my current setup.  Help much appreciated.

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int    age;

    public Person(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class Producer extends Thread
{
    private Model model;

    public Producer(Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Person fred     = new Person("Fred Flintstone", 37);
        Person wilma    = new Person("Wilma Flintstone", 18);
        Person pebbles  = new Person("Pebbles Flintstone", 15);
        Person dino     = new Person("Dino Flintstone", 45);
        Person barney   = new Person("Barney Rubble", 76);
        Person betty    = new Person("Betty Rubble", 76);
        Person bamm     = new Person("Bamm-Bamm Rubble", 76);

        try
        {
            model.addPerson(fred);
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            model.addPerson(wilma);
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            model.addPerson(pebbles);
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            model.addPerson(dino);
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            model.addPerson(barney);
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            model.addPerson(betty);
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            model.addPerson(bamm);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error adding Person object to Model.people
                                ArrayList" + e);
        }
    }
}

public class Model 
{
    private List <Person> people;

    public Model()
    {
        people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }

    public List<Person> getPeople()
    {
        return people;
    }

    public void addPerson(Person aPerson)
    {
        people.add(aPerson);
        System.out.println("Person object added to people list:" + aPerson);
    }

    public void removePerson(Person aPerson)
    {
        people.remove(aPerson);
    }
}

public class View extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel              topPanel, botPanel;
    private JList               peopleList;
    private JScrollPane         scrollPane;
    private Model               model;

    public View(Model model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        setSize(200, 220);
        setTitle("View");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        botPanel = new JPanel();
        peopleList = new JList(model.getPeople().toArray());
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(peopleList);
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        topPanel.add(scrollPane);
        topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder
       (BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "People list"));

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        cp.add(botPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Model model = new Model();
        View theView = new View(model);
        theView.setVisible(true);
        Producer producer = new Producer(model);
        producer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use appropriate MVC-pattern here: Views listen for changes in the model and update according to notifications from the model:

1. Add `PropertyChangeSupport` on your model and fire `PropertyChangeEvent`'s when modifying your model
2. Add the view as a `PropertyChangeListener` of your model
3. React to the notifications accordingly (if a `Person` is added to your model, when you receive the event that says "New person added", add it to the `ListModel` of your `peopleList`, same for "Person removed", etc...)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html

Note: Since your model will be modified by another Thread than the EDT (Event dispatching Thread), make sure that you modify your UI on the EDT (Take a look at `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchingThread()` and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`)

UPDATE:

Here is a snippet that illustrates what I was trying to explain above (sorry if it is a bit lengthy but I tried to stay as close as possible to your original code):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    public class Person {

        private String name;
        private int age;

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }

    public class Producer extends Thread {
        private Model model;

        public Producer(Model model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random random = new Random();
            Person fred = new Person("Fred Flintstone", 37);
            Person wilma = new Person("Wilma Flintstone", 18);
            Person pebbles = new Person("Pebbles Flintstone", 15);
            Person dino = new Person("Dino Flintstone", 45);
            Person barney = new Person("Barney Rubble", 76);
            Person betty = new Person("Betty Rubble", 76);
            Person bamm = new Person("Bamm-Bamm Rubble", 76);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    model.addPerson(fred);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    model.addPerson(wilma);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    model.addPerson(pebbles);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    model.addPerson(dino);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    model.addPerson(barney);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    model.addPerson(betty);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    model.addPerson(bamm);
                    while (model.getPeople().size() > 0) {
                        Person p = model.getPeople().get(random.nextInt(model.getPeople().size()));
                        model.removePerson(p);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Model {
        private static final String PEOPLE = "people";

        private List<Person> people;

        private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

        public Model() {
            people = new ArrayList<Person>();
            propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        }

        public PropertyChangeSupport getPropertyChangeSupport() {
            return propertyChangeSupport;
        }

        public List<Person> getPeople() {
            return people;
        }

        public void addPerson(Person aPerson) {
            people.add(aPerson);
            System.out.println("Person object added to people list:" + aPerson);
            getPropertyChangeSupport().firePropertyChange(PEOPLE, null, aPerson);
        }

        public void removePerson(Person aPerson) {
            people.remove(aPerson);
            getPropertyChangeSupport().firePropertyChange(PEOPLE, aPerson, null);
        }
    }

    public class View extends JFrame implements PropertyChangeListener {
        private JPanel topPanel, botPanel;
        private JList peopleList;
        private JScrollPane scrollPane;
        private Model model;
        private DefaultListModel peopleListModel;

        public View(Model model) {
            this.model = model;
            setSize(200, 220);
            setTitle("View");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            topPanel = new JPanel();
            botPanel = new JPanel();
            peopleListModel = new DefaultListModel();
            for (Person p : model.getPeople()) {
                peopleListModel.addElement(p);
            }
            peopleList = new JList(peopleListModel);
            model.getPropertyChangeSupport().addPropertyChangeListener(Model.PEOPLE, this);
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(peopleList);
            topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            topPanel.add(scrollPane);
            topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "People list"));

            Container cp = getContentPane();
            cp.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            cp.add(botPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        propertyChange(evt);
                    }
                });
                return;
            }
            if (evt.getSource() == model) {
                if (Model.PEOPLE.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    if (evt.getOldValue() != null && evt.getNewValue() == null) {
                        peopleListModel.removeElement(evt.getOldValue());
                    } else if (evt.getOldValue() == null && evt.getNewValue() != null) {
                        peopleListModel.addElement(evt.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().init();
    }

    private void init() {
        final Model model = new Model();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                View theView = new View(model);
                theView.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        Producer producer = new Producer(model);
        producer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+. Also would use the Swing variant of PropertyChangeSupport, namely use a [SwingPropertyChangeSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/SwingPropertyChangeSupport.html) object to help ensure that the PropertyChangeListeners are notified on the Swing event thread.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes I read about that and it can be convenient in some case but my personal opinion is that a Model should never rely/depend on UI-technology. If you use SwingPropertyChangeSupport, you will indirectly use SwingUtilities.invokeLater which could start the AWT-EventQueue. Now, if you are running that code in SWT, you will get an error as SWT and AWT cannot live together in the same JVM. But good point in case the user only ever focuses on Swing.

Comment: @Paul is a newbie - please don't confuse him :-) The major problem is to understand that modifications to the datastructure (the people list in Model) are not automatically seen by the ListModel which is wrapped around it. So the major solution is to implement a custom ListModel which fires the appropriate ListDataEvents. A minor problem (which he didn't yet stumbled across) is that a listDataEvent must be fired on changes of a property (like f.i. name) of a contained Person. That's where PropertyChangeEvents come into play.

Comment: @kleopatra I am not sure Paul is a complete newbie since he obviously found about ListModel/DefaultListModel. He also clearly tried to set up an MVC pattern. Property change support can also come into play for data structure changes. All that is left to do is to manipulate the DefaultListModel according to notifications. I updated my post with a complete example code (mainly based on the OP code).

Comment: that's hard on the borderline of a valid propertyChangeEvent ;-) It could be a notification-only property if you rename the getPeople() method to something else. It's possible but not overly extensible: f.i. what happens if you start listening to propertyChanges on Person (assuming that will evolve into a bean)? PropertyChanges simply aren't meant to notification about structure modifications - the impedance mismatch will drive you crazy in the longer run. The clean way out is an observable datastructure (which also has its issues, though)

Comment: Thanks for all of the ideas for this.  Sadly I'm not a complete newbie, I just struggle sometimes putting into practise in real situations what I've learned.

Comment: @Paul - sorry, didn't mean to offend :-) But don't use a PropertyChangeEvent to notify about datastructure modifications, it's simply not designed for that purpose.

Comment: @kleopatra what would you suggest to use to notify datastructure changes?

Comment: a custom event that is rich enough

Comment: @kleopatra so this means to have an additional notification mechanisms? Is not this going to be soon a giant mess (views will have to carefully register/unregister themselves on one mechanism or the other, etc...)? Also resulting in more code on observer-side and preventing to use generic observation mechanisms. Is there a clean way to extend PCS or is there an alternative to PCS?

Comment: no mess, all you need a sound observable dataStructure independent of any concrete ui framework. Then write one adapter from such a observable into the view for each framework and you are ready. And no, a PCS isn't designed for such and most probably not extensible, its semantics are simply too mis-fitting.

Comment: No offence taken kleopatra :).  This debate has really helped me get a better understanding of what it is I need to be doing, so a big thanks to kleopatra and Guillaume.  I have to admit the PropertyChangeEvent works well but seems over-complicated for what I need (Please don't take any offence Guillaume, because your answer was above and beyond).  I've been looking into using the Observer pattern, which appears a less complex solution.